# On click if statement not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can someone please explain to me why this is working:

```
  function updateWellnessPrice() {
        $('#toggle_151, #toggle_170').click(function () {
            amount = '1.50';
            $('#toggle_153 input').attr('data-amount', amount);
            $('#toggle_153 span').html(amount);
        });

    $('#toggle_148, #toggle_149, #toggle_150, #toggle_167, #toggle_168, #toggle_169').click(function () {
        amount = '0';
        $('#toggle_153 input').attr('data-amount', amount);
        $('#toggle_153 span').html(amount);
    });
};
```

But I do not like that code I want to write it shorthanded. Why is this code below not working?

```
  $('#toggle_151, #toggle_170').click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        if($this.data('clicked') == true) {
            amount = '1.50';
        } else {
            console.log('check');
            amount = '0';
        }
        $('#toggle_153 input').attr('data-amount', amount);
        $('#toggle_153 span').html(amount);
    });
```

Even the console log is not showing up so he does not like the else in that click function.

Comment: Why don't you  use (consistently) data() to get all data-* attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if you `if` condition is making any sense here

Try this

```
$('#toggle_148, #toggle_149, #toggle_150, #toggle_167, #toggle_168, #toggle_169, #toggle_151, #toggle_170').click(function () {
    var currentId = $(this).attr( "id" );
    if( currentId == "toggle_151" || currentId == "toggle_170" ) 
    {
        amount = '1.50';
    } 
    else 
    {
        console.log('check');
        amount = '0';
    }
    $('#toggle_153 input').attr('data-amount', amount);
    $('#toggle_153 span').html(amount);
});
```

Now this is assuming that you want to write a single click handler for all the ids.

Answer (score 0):

Look at your if statement

```
if($this.data('clicked') == true)
```

so every time you click the button it will be true, it will never go to else statement. Instead you can try this

```
function updateWellnessPrice() {
    $('#toggle_151, #toggle_170').click(function () {
        amount = '1.50';
        update(amount);
    });

    $('#toggle_148, #toggle_149, #toggle_150, #toggle_167, #toggle_168, #toggle_169').click(function () {
        amount = '0';
        update(amount);
    });

    function update(amount){
        $('#toggle_153 input').attr('data-amount', amount);
        $('#toggle_153 span').html(amount);
    }
};
```